# Get current url of the popup window with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I had a webpage with a link, which opens a new page in a popup window.
Everything is fine till here, The popup window contains credit card payment page held by some 3rd party server. After completing the payment flow the response is shown and there is change in the url.

I need to get that url.

Is it is possible in javascript?

Comment: It is possible with Javascript, if the Javascript runs on the page of the URL. You said it is a third party page. If you are trying to get the URL from a third party page that the user was redirected to from your page - I don't think this is possible.

Comment: No, javascript runs on our page and not on the third party page.

Answer (score 21):

The URL of a page is accessible through the [location](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location) property of the window object. If you are visiting a site on the same subdomain as you , then you can get the address via

```
popupWindow.location.href
```

However, if the popup is from a third party, the [same origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript) applies and you are not allowed to inspect the location.href of the popup. The only ways to bypass the same origin policy would involve cooperation from the third party.

Comment: Yes buddy I tried this but as you said rightly the third party is not allowing to inspect the location properties.

Answer (score -3):

Google is your friend  ;D

```
 var newURL = window.location.protocol + "://" + window.location.host + "/" 
              + window.location.pathname;
```

Comment: Its simpler to just use window.location.href for that. And if you had checked, you would see that you are not allowed to inspect the window.location of a popup to a third party website.